# How to use Unicode font on Windows Mobile 6.x

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, windows-mobile

I have a Window Mobile application that I'd like to display Arabic characters in. I have tried copying MS Arial Unicode to the Fonts folder and the Windows folder (and then restarting, of course!). I then marked the dialog font as MS Arial Unicode in the .rc file and (when that didn't work) also manually setting the font of the window using WM_SETFONT. It appears to me that Windows Mobile ignores the font - do I need to do more than copy it for an application to be able to reference that font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `AddFontResource()` with the file you copied, and perform a reset.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the call fails for me:
`AddFontResource(TEXT("\\Windows\\ARIALUNI.TTF")); // returns 0 :-(`

Any other ideas?

Comment: I renamed the file to be lowercase arialuni.ttf and now the AddFontResource call works. Unbelievable! The GetLastError call was stating "file not found" so I played around.
:-)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I'm glad to hear it worked in the end :)